# How to find the text/number between 2 characters, the last being a non-unique comma using Excel formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The challenge is to find the number between "produto_id:" and the last character, which is sometimes a "]" or a " , ". When it's a "]", it does extract the text, but it doesn't when it's a comma.

The cell value:

```
linha:2,quantidade:2,preco_cheio:19.9000,preco_promocional:null,preco_venda:19.9000,preco_custo:null,produto_id:27319353,
```

The formula I'm using, which works when the last character is a ]:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(MID(LEFT($AV9;SEARCH("]";$AV9)-1);SEARCH("produto_id:";$AV9)+11;LEN($AV9)));"")
```

For the occurrences ending in a comma:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(MID(LEFT($AV9;SEARCH(",";$AV9)-1);SEARCH("produto_id:";$AV9)+11;LEN($AV9)));"")
```

I'd appreciate if you could give it a glance and let me know where I'm failing.

Thanks.

Comment: So, what would be your output from given data. You may use `FILTERXML()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `B1`, formula copied down :

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("produto_id",A1)+11,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("produto_id",A1)-11)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Antonio here is a solution for your problem:

Portuguese formula:

```
=SUBSTITUIR(SUBSTITUIR(EXT.TEXTO(A2;LOCALIZAR("produto_id:";A2;1)+11;NÚM.CARACT(A2)-(LOCALIZAR("produto_id:";A2;1)+10));",";"");"]";"")
```

English formula:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(MID(A2;SEARCH("produto_id:";A2;1)+11;LEN(A2)-(SEARCH("produto_id:";A2;1)+10));",";"");"]";"")
```

replace A2 for your cell.

Comment: Thanks, Mateus! Eu acabei usando a outra solução, que foi dada antes da sua, mas a sua é muito boa, tb! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on below `FILTERXML()` formula.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>"),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., 'produto_id:')]"),":","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[last()]")
```

[image]

Comment: Comma and semicolon depends on reginal & language settings. You may need to replace comma with semicolon in your case.

Comment: Thank you! I've ended up using the solution given prior to yours, but this is great learning new ways to tackle it!